# How to implement an 'outer join' relationship in SQL Server? 

Tags: sql-server, database-design, relational-database, database-schema, outer-join

This is a question that's probably going to incur the wrath of some DBA types but I'm gonna ask it anyway!!

I have a SQL Server DB and we are adding a new table which is basically going to act as a lookup table. We'll call it `tblLookup`. There is another table called `tblMain`.

Every row in `tblMain` will either have *none or one* related row(s) in `tblLookup`. So `tblLookup` contains the "primary key" (although it's not actually the primary key of the table) and `tblMain` contains the "foreign key".

SQL Server  won't let me add this relationship even if I set **enforce foreign key constraint** to **no**.

What am I best off doing? Obviously I can define this relationship when `SELECT`ing by doing a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` - but I would prefer it if there was something in the schema itself (I'm not sure what benefit I'm hoping to get? Maybe someone can tell me!)

Comment: Generally helps to have code being tried and error messages to troubleshoot this sort of thing.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? If you don't want to enforce a constraint on this data then there's no point trying to create one. Just put a uniqueness constraint in the "lookup" table on the column(s) that these tables have in common - that way you'll enforce the "not more than one" constraint.

Comment: Including the relevant table definition will help.  Also, what is the error when you try to add the constraint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're asking, how can I implement a foreign key constraint, where the referenced values are not unique? In other words all non-NULL values in TableA.ColumnA must already be present in TableB.ColumnB, but the values in TableB.ColumnB are not unique.

If so, a trigger could easily enforce this, but you should consider your design as well before making that decision. Why are the values you want to reference not unique? Perhaps there's a genuine reason for it, but it's also possible that you should extract the distinct values into a third table and then have foreign keys from both your other tables. Without more information about your database and what you're modelling it's impossible to say what the best approach here is.

Finally, and for what it's worth, "lookup tables" are often understood to be tables that have a well-defined primary key and are referenced by it and only by it in foreign keys e.g. countries, currencies, products etc. To avoid confusion when asking your question, you should probably choose different table names or - even better - provide a self-contained SQL example that illustrates your problem unambiguously.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to create the foreign key relationship in the wrong direction. You'd want to create a relationship *from* `tblLookup` *to* `tblMain`. Something like:

```
ALTER TABLE tblLookup
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_tblLookup_tblMain FOREIGN KEY (tblMain_id)
    REFERENCES tblMain (id);
```

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks for your response. I know it seems as though I'm doing it the wrong way but the problem is the lookup field is not unique in `tblMain`...